# How to add start-end tags to xml output of log4net in windows service app on c#

Tags: c#, xml, log4net

I configured log4net in my C# project like below:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="\Logs\SocketListenerLogs" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <datePattern value="-yyyy-MM-dd.\x\m\l"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="4096KB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
      <layout type="MessageProcessors.MyXmlLayout" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="WARN" />
      </filter>
</appender>
```

In this case, log4net generates my output in xml format. However, I did not like the default xml format and I override it in `MyXmlLayout:log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutBase` class by using `protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent){...}` method.

This is a socketlistener application and it is working as a windows service. When I start the service, it generates the log file `SocketListenerLogs-2016-07-22.xml` (uses always today's date). And whenever a client sends a message to server, it logs the message inside my `LogMessage(string message)` function. An example of the output is:

```
<message client="client1" server="server1">
    THIS IS MESSAGE 1
</message>

<message client="client2" server="server2">
    THIS IS MESSAGE 2
</message>

<message client="client3" server="server3">
    THIS IS MESSAGE 3
</message>
```

My problem is that the XML file cannot be validated because there is no start-end tags including all the codes. The output should be like:

```
<startXML>
    <message client="client1" server="server1">
        THIS IS MESSAGE 1
    </message>
    ...
</startXML>
```

So, I am stucked at that point, because I cannot read the file with StreamReader and add the tags to the first/last lines manually since the file is used by the windows service and it would give the error below when I try to read it manually in the code: System.IO.IOException: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

What is the best way to solve this problem? Is there any way for log4net to add some default tags while generating its output at the beginning? Note that when I start the service now it immediately generates a blank output .xml file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is all covered in [the documentation for XmlLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Layout_XmlLayout.htm)

> The output of the XmlLayout consists of a series of log4net:event elements. **It does not output a complete well-formed XML file. The output is designed to be included as an external entity in a separate file to form a correct XML file.**

And:

> … the Header and Footer properties can be configured to output the correct XML header, open tag and close tag.

Comment: it is good to learn that it can be configured, but how I couldnt find :(